# Synchronizing local parse server to cloud parse server

Tags: parse-server

Here is my situation i have a local parse server to which all my client devices are primarily connected due to the lack of consistent internet resource availability.
I intend to have a cloud hosted parse server to which the local parse can data sync with (pull and push) whenever there is availability of internet resources which may be periodic . How can that be achieved ?
The idea is to sync data between both parse servrr instances

Comment: You are talking about source control sync (like git) or data sync ?

Answer (score 0):

You know that parse-server by itself does not save your data.
What am sure you are trying to refer to is your database.

The best way to go is to export and import your mongo data as needed from your remote db source to your remote data source when you have internet connectivity.

You may also try ngrok.com for temporary network tunneling if that is what you need