# Setting up replica parse-server instances

Tags: parse-server

How do i set up a mirroring for two parse server instances where one is available locally and one is cloud hosted.
The two parse server instances are to maintain data consistency and are both to be fully functional.
the essence of the locally available parse server is for scenarios of internet connectivity outage.
Data is to be synchronized not source code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronizing local parse server to cloud parse server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134664/synchronizing-local-parse-server-to-cloud-parse-server)

Answer (score 2):

Your parse-server stores its data in mongodb. If you have two parse-server instances sharing the same data, you need to use the same mongo database for these two instances (same databaseURI parameter).

If you want redundancy on the database, you can deploy a replica set for your mongo database. This is quite easy, but you will need at least 3 servers. Two of them would store the data, the third one can be an arbiter. Please refer to mongo doc:
[MongoDB: Deploy a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/)

You can also find many tutorials explaining how to deploy a replica set.